# Running out of memory due to large variables Python

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, out-of-memory, bigdata, pymongo

I am working with a large Mongo collection containing millions of tweets. I am using a remote ubuntu server to run a Python script that calls some methods to analyze the tweets and stores the results of the analysis in a separate collection. However, the script gets killed and I suspect it is because I am running out of memory.

Some of the analyses I am doing are textual analyses. They include things like: detecting most frequent hashtags / mentions, analyzing hashtags cooccurrences etc. Sometimes, I need to perform such analyses on many thousands of tweets at a time. What I usually do is I create a variable where I store all of the tweets' text, and then pass that variable to the methods that give me the data I want (e.g. which are the most frequent hashtags, etc). I create the variable containing the tweets' text like this:

```
cursor = tweets_data_mongo_collection.find(query, {"_id": 0, "text": 1}, no_cursor_timeout = True)
tweets_text = ""
for doc in cursor:
    tweets_text = tweets_text + " " + doc["text"]
```

Then I pass tweets_text to whatever method for textual analysis, and store the result of the analysis in a Mongo collection.

As I said, the code runs find for a bit but then gets killed. I am inclined to think that this is because of how I am working with tweets' textual data: working with variables such as tweets_text in the above snippet can consume a lot of memory when the cursor returns a large number of tweets.

However, I am not sure about how I could overcome this issue. I am quite new to working with big data so I am wondering whether I am unaware of some pretty basic changes that I could make to my code / approach to avoid these memory issues.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to add a `limit` to the find and use `join` to concatenate the results, e.g.

```
cursor = tweets_data_mongo_collection.find(query, {"_id": 0, "text": 1},
                                           no_cursor_timeout = True).limit(100000)
tweets_text = " ".join(list(cursor))
```

If you still have memory issues you can use [tracemalloc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tracemalloc.html) (or similar) to debug the memory allocations.